# Cambiar name a etiqueta XML

Tags: vb.net, xml, aeat-sii

¿Como puedo cambiar el `name` de un `tag` de un XML ya generado?

Tengo un fichero XML de este estilo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:siiLR="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd" xmlns:sii="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">
    <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas xmlns:Sii="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd" xmlns:SiiLR="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd">
                <sii:Cabecera>
                    <sii:IDVersionSii>0.6</sii:IDVersionSii>
                    <sii:Titular>
                        <sii:NombreRazon>EMPRESAXXXX</sii:NombreRazon>
                        <sii:NIF>A84532501</sii:NIF>
                    </sii:Titular>
                    <sii:TipoComunicacion>A0</sii:TipoComunicacion>
                </sii:Cabecera>
                <siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
                    <sii:PeriodoImpositivo>
                        <sii:Ejercicio>2015</sii:Ejercicio>
                        <sii:Periodo>01</sii:Periodo>
                    </sii:PeriodoImpositivo>
                    <siiLR:IDFactura>
                        <sii:IDEmisorFactura>
                            <sii:NIF>A84532501</sii:NIF>
                        </sii:IDEmisorFactura>
                        <sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>01</sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
                        <sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>15-01-2015</sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
                    </siiLR:IDFactura>
                    <siiLR:FacturaExpedida>
                        <sii:TipoFactura>F1</sii:TipoFactura>
                        <sii:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</sii:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
                        <sii:ImporteTotal>26.70</sii:ImporteTotal>
                        <sii:DescripcionOperacion>CompraXXXXXXX</sii:DescripcionOperacion>
                        <sii:Contraparte>
                            <sii:NombreRazon>EMPRESAYYYYYYYY</sii:NombreRazon>
                            <sii:NIF>94234500B</sii:NIF>
                        </sii:Contraparte>
                        <sii:TipoDesglose>
                            <sii:DesgloseFactura>
                                <sii:Sujeta>
                                    <sii:NoExenta>
                                        <sii:TipoNoExenta>S1</sii:TipoNoExenta>
                                        <sii:DesgloseIVA>
                                            <sii:DetalleIVA>
                                                <sii:TipoImpositivo>21</sii:TipoImpositivo>
                                                <sii:BaseImponible>22.07</sii:BaseImponible>
                                                <sii:CuotaRepercutida>4.63</sii:CuotaRepercutida>
                                                <sii:TipoRecargoEquivalencia>0</sii:TipoRecargoEquivalencia>
                                                <sii:CuotaRecargoEquivalencia>0</sii:CuotaRecargoEquivalencia>
                                            </sii:DetalleIVA>
                                        </sii:DesgloseIVA>
                                    </sii:NoExenta>
                                </sii:Sujeta>
                            </sii:DesgloseFactura>
                        </sii:TipoDesglose>
                    </siiLR:FacturaExpedida>
                </siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
            </SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Todas las etiquetas que están dentro del nivel de la etiqueta `<soapenv:Body>` tienen el prefijo *`Sii`* o *`SiiLR`*.

La etiqueta `<SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>` debería tener el prefijo *`SiiLR`* pero no lo tiene.

El tag `<SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>` debe ser `<SiiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>`

Al intentar cambiarlo es donde tengo el problema:

He intentado:

Opción 1:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(RutaDelXml)    
Dim root As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas")
root(0).Name = "SiiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas"
```

Pero el Name es `ReadOnly` por lo que no puedo cambiarlo.

Opción 2:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(String.Format(RutaXml)
Dim Nodo As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas")
If Nodo IsNot Nothing Then
    Nodo.Prefix = "SiiLR"
End If
doc.Save(RutaXmlNueva)
```

Al cambiar el *`Prefix`*, en el objeto `Nodo`, el Name me muestra `<SiiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>` que es correcto, pero al hacer el `Save` del `XmlDocument`, el cambio no se aplica.

Opción 3: Con esta lo he conseguido, pero no me gusta demasiado y seguro que hay una forma mejor de hacerlo:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(RutaXml)
Dim texto As String = doc.InnerXml
Dim encontrado As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(texto, "<SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas ").ToString
texto = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(texto, "<SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas ", "<SiiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas ")
texto = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(texto, "</SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas.*>", "</SiiLR:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>")
doc.InnerXml = texto
doc.Save(RutaXmlNueva)
```

Recupero el contenido del `Xml` en un `string`, hago el `replace` mediante expresiones regulares y guardo el resultado en un nuevo `xml`.

Como comento, la opción 3 funciona, pero me gustaría vuestra opinión al respecto.

Comment: puedes agregar el código que intentaste?

Comment: Creo que la mejor opción si puedes es arreglarlo directamente a la hora de generarlo, esa sería la opción ideal, no sé cómo/quién lo genera pero yo desde PHP con SoapClient simplemente le paso un array de datos y el cliente soap se encarga de crear el XML antes de enviarlo y le coloca todas las etiquetas bien sin tener que tocar nada de XML. De hecho monte un ebook con ejemplos en PHP que se encuentra aquí http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/

Comment: La solucion "elegante" que buscases bastante dispendiosa dadas las restricciones del XML DOM. Tendrías que crear un nuevo objeto XmlElement con el namspace que necesitas, luego copiar los elementos usando cloneNode, borrar el elemento original y finalmente copiar el nuevo elemento que creaste. A menos que en algún momento cambien los prefijos que se usan en este servicio la solución de la Expresión Regular te va a funcionar sin problema